# SQL Lab--Creating indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

How do we solve this? I tried it but getting the wrong answer.
Indexes are data structures used by the database to improve query performance. Of course, the trade-off is that indexes must be maintained (as their corresponding tables are updated).

Write a query to look up all customers with the first name John in mg customer. Then ask the database to show how the query is performed using:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your query ...>
```

In the comments, write the kind of scan used, and the time required to execute.

When a customer is checking out, they typically provide their last and first name. To speed up the querying of their customer record, create an index called first last over the `first_name` and `last_name` columns (in that order) on the mg customer table.

The syntax is:

```
CREATE INDEX <index name> ON <table name> (<attribute 1>, ..., <attribute n>)
```

Again, ask the database to show how the above query is performed. Does the kind of scan change? Does the time required to execute change? Write your answers in the comments.

Comment: For the most part, people aren't going to be interested in helping with obvious homework questions.

Comment: Additionally, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is not MySQL syntax.  This is related to an RDBMS other than MySQL.